# SSO Between Websphere Portal and Moodle

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, moodle, websphere-portal

We have a vendor portal that is public and a Moodle site that is also public.  They are both setup to use the same Active Directory.

Is there a way to configure sso between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into this issue before, and all that I've found is about keeping the user credential in the global Portal session and posting them to the server Moodle login form.

It seems that Moodle does not support LTPA, since this is a proprietary IBM protocol designed for Websphere and Domino. Also the LTPA token do not include the actual password, so Moodle would have to trust Websphere when it says that a particular user has been authenticated at a certain time (timestamp).

May be some one else might have more input on the subject...